# Simple python syntax

Tags: python

My code pulls data from a csv file. I want to add a header to it. I am confused where to put the print statement so it will be at the beginning of the file (as a header).

```
import csv
import StringIO

f = open('/home/unica/app/Affinium/Campaign/partitions/partition1/scripts/runscripts/campaigns/cnyr/dev/output/CNYR_DM_TM_CAMPAIGN_WAVES.csv', 'r')

try:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    if row[16] == "" and row[5].find('_NOEMAIL_'):
       if row[6]== 'DM':
          print(  row[17]+'|'+row[16]+'|'+row[25]+'|'+row[18]+'|'+row[20]+'|'+row[21]+'|'+row[19]+'|'+row[26]+'|'+row[27]+'|'+row[28]+'|'+row[29]+'|'+row[30]+'|'+row[31]+'|'+row[32]+'|'+row[8]+'|'+row[36]+'|'+row[35]+'|'+row[37]+'|'+row[34] )
```

there is multiple if statement and I want header before each case.So I was putting it after if and before printing the rows.The result which I am getting is

```
PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,...
,J,8,,NUSRALA,,EDWARD...
PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,...
,J,614,,BACAL,,LEON...
```

So definitely I wasnt asking for this.Seems it is searchng for every row and returning every time it is looping over.Any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Erm, before you start working on the file?

Comment: How about a little experimentation? Try adding a print statement in various places and see which one works.

Comment: I tried adding after import string.and also I tried before if statement.But cant see it.

Comment: maybe you are always getting an index error in your try/except  so you never get as far as the print statement

Comment: So you understand the intended usage of "print" statements right??

Comment: `print` is not meant to write to the CSV file. It's meant to output to the stream/console. For the header to be above all other lines, write it before doing the `for` loop. See the relevant Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: I think your mistake is that you think you can edit a file in-place. In general, you can't. (There are special cases where you can, but they're not important here.) What you want to do here is write a new file, then move that on top of the old one. And you want to write the new file using `csv.writer`, just as you're reading the old one with `csv.reader`; otherwise you're going to completely break the quoting, etc.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am not getting index error.I wanted to get the data with the header which i want to print on the top .so I was confused where to put the print statement.Reading here it seems I have to put before FOR loop.

Comment: @Rajarshi, if you are getting no output either your condition is never True or you are getting an index error

Comment: I am getting output ...its a huge file but the problem is I cant see the top of unix environment.i am not that familiar with putty commands. Can i put some export or redirect my output to another file.

Comment: yes, use ">>output.txt" without the quotes, in the console, at the end of your call

Comment: Important thing why the O/P by default carrying the first row from CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. please indent code after the `try:` to make the program work ;)
2. the right place for printing your header line would be right before the line containing `try:`
3. I assume you want the data to be printed in a tabular way, i.e. neatly aligned, so that your `+'|'+` are forming vertical lines. Please investivate the `string.format` method regarding this. I assume your code to look like `print( "{0:<30s}|...".format(row[17],...) )` after you are done. Please [check the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) how this works.
4. Your program will not "edit" the csv in any way but just neatly print its content. Should you wish to filter and re-arrange the fields in that file, you might consider using `awk`

Comment: yes you are right it a tubular way where the data is in variable length.but the problem is i put the print statement before and after try but still dnt get any header in o/p.maybe because the file itself is huge so I cant scroll up in the putty screen.Can you tell me a way.

Comment: Important thing why the O/P by default carrying the first row from CSV file

Comment: You can employ operating systems tools to make long output browsable. Assuming your program is in a file named `x.py`, you can pipe the output to `more` or `less`: `python3 x.py | less`. You might also consider to add a little counter and repeat the header line after, say, exery 30 lines printed.

Comment: I would like to know more how to take out the first row which coming default in my o/p.is it because of the function I used to fetch data.